# Preventing comments being made on Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have setup a page for my company and restricted posting to admins only, but when an admin posts something, the option to Like or Comment is visible for everyone, including those who are not "liking" the page. This means anyone can "like" or "comment" on posts.

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's quest to make the world more open means that logged in Facebook users are allowed to comment and like everywhere. So, no, you aren't able to block this behavior.

The only other option you have is to make a closed group, but it would be hard for people to find the page with this method.